# Object is already used when use same q-object in QueryDSL

Tags: java, hibernate, querydsl

Hi I have Hibernate project with QUeryDSL 3.6.0, when I have in my service class only findAll() methods, everyThing was OK. But whe I add findByID an error appears.

```
    public class ArticleServiceImpl extends ArticleService {

        QArticle article = QArticle.article;

        @Override
        public List<Article> findAll() {
            return query.from(article).fetchAll().list(article);
        }

        public Article findById(@Nonnull final long id) {
            return query.from(article).where(article.id.eq(id)).uniqueResult(article);
        }
    }
```

An the error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: article is already used
    at com.mysema.query.DefaultQueryMetadata.addJoin(DefaultQueryMetadata.java:160)
    at com.mysema.query.support.QueryMixin.from(QueryMixin.java:189)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.JPAQueryBase.from(JPAQueryBase.java:88)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.JPAQueryBase.from(JPAQueryBase.java:32)
    at com.example.hibernate.services.ArticleServiceImpl.findById(ArticleServiceImpl.java:30)
    at com.example.hibernate.core.Main.main(Main.java:42)
```

What happens? I saw that queries are not tread-safe. But how to use Q-class in the two different methods?

Edit:

```
protected JPQLQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
```

it is protected variable that comes from ArticleService.

Comment: How do you construct the query instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This exception is thrown whenever there is a repeatable call to the same generated `QEntity` in `from()` clause for the same instance of `JPAQuery()`.

Here is an example (*DISCLAIMER*: This is going to be very, very dumb example just to illustrate the problem).

Let's say we have an entity called `MyEntity`, and we try to get two `MyEntity`'s from a database in a way, that the first result will be for a given `id`, and the second result will be the one which has `id+1`

```
public List<MyEntity> findMyDumbEntities(long id) {    
      QMyEntity qMyEntity = QMyEntity.myEntity;
      JPAQuery jpaQuery = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
      MyEntity myFirstEntity = jpaQuery.from(qMyEntity).where(qMyEntity.id.eq(id)).uniqueResult(qMyEntity);
      MyEntity mySecondEntity = jpaQuery.from(qMyEntity).where(qMyEntity.id.eq(id+1)).uniqueResult(qMyEntity);

      return Arrays.asList(myFirstEntity, mySecondEntity);    
}
```

And when trying to call this method we will see the following exception:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: qMyEntity is already used
```

Why? Because we have one instance of `JPAQuery` and we are repeating call to the same entity (we have two `jpqQuery.from(qMyEntity)`). To solve the problem we just need to get JPAQuery instance each time we want to query something, so we need to change our code to

```
public List<MyEntity> findMyDumbEntities(long id) {        
          QMyEntity qMyEntity = QMyEntity.myEntity;
          MyEntity myFirstEntity = new JPAQuery(entityManager).from(qMyEntity).where(qMyEntity.id.eq(id)).uniqueResult(qMyEntity);
          MyEntity mySecondEntity = new JPAQuery(entityManager).from(qMyEntity).where(qMyEntity.id.eq(id+1)).uniqueResult(qMyEntity);

          return Arrays.asList(myFirstEntity, mySecondEntity);        
}
```

So to fix your problem, instead of having JPQQuery initialized once

```
protected JPQLQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
```

Change that you get each time new JPAQuery, for example

```
protected JPQLQuery jpaQuery() {
    return new JPAQuery(entityManager);
}
```

And then in your service implementation

```
@Override
public List<Article> findAll() {
      return jpaQuery().from(article).fetchAll().list(article);
}

public Article findById(@Nonnull final long id) {
      return jpaQuery().from(article).where(article.id.eq(id)).uniqueResult(article);
}
```

Comment: OK that fix my problem, but I still do not understand why this is not happen when for example in the And then in your service implementation in you example we have one Q-type object - article, which is shared between findAll() and findById(@Nonnull final long id), methods. Why then there is not article is already used??

Comment: The problem is not with the generated Q-type object, but that we use that QType object with the same instance of JPAQuery twice (I updated my answer to be more clear). You will always have one Q-type object in fact, and will reuse it everywhere, but you can't reuse it more than once for the same instance of  JPAQuery(). Hope that helps.